# Design is broken at 110% zoom

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

At 110% zoom on Chrome on Windows 7 the current design on meta looks like this to me:

[image]

It looks perfectly fine at 100% zoom, and this only happens on the frontpage and not the questions list. But there seems to be some problem that makes the whole layout fall apart at differnt zoom levels.

Comment: Same behavior for me

Comment: Issue does *not* occur in Firefox v28 on OSX 10.8.5

Comment: I can replicate on Chrome/OSX. Oddly, it's *only* 110% that has the issue. I'd chalk it up to bizarre Chrome bug.

Comment: I no longer have this behavior at 110%, nor anything tested in the range of 50-300% on Chrome 40/Windows 8.1. Can anyone else confirm? cc @DA01

Comment: @JohnB looks good to me. Google must have fixed the bug!

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a bug previously in Chrome, DA01 and I can no longer produce the issue.

Comment: Fine here as well in Chrome 40/64bit